# How to achieve different item heights in sliver grid

Tags: dart, flutter, height, sliver-grid

I want to create a shopping cart app. I used a Sliver grid having different items with different heights but it's not working. Please help

[grid in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GZCb.png)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: How to implement it in a custom scroll view? Does it have any sliver options?

Comment: You can read its documentation. Yes it has many sliver options https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view-library.html

Comment: It's good to have that feature included here but they have a lot of issues though I couldn't use container in a tile widget.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your particular problem but it may help anyone who just wants to resize the height of all SliverGrid items.

I had a similar problem and went to view the [docs here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid-class.html). There is no explicit way to declare the height but I used `childAspectRatio` property of the `SliverGridDelegate`. A ratio of 1 means the sliver item retains its preset height. Any ratio above 1 reduces the height. In order to increase the height, I used a decimal ratio.

```
childAspectRatio: 0.5,
```

Here is the complete code of the SliverGrid and its delegate as well as a simple render of placeholder items:

```
SliverGrid(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 0.5,
        ),
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Text(
                  "Item $index"
              ),
            );
          },
          childCount: 10,
        ),
      )
```

Please note that this will change the height of all grid items.